# PHP - Can I set a function bool parameter instantly to true?

Tags: php

```php
<?php
  class myURLs{
    function myPHP($files, $include=true){ //$files => Array[2] ; $include => Bool
      $f = myURLs::myFile($files, "php", "php"); //$f => Array[count($files)]
      if($include)
        myURLs::myInclution($f);
      else {
        return $f;
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

I mean the **`$include=true`** part of the function `myPHP`. I'm not sure if its right to set the bool to true within the function.
What do you mean?

Comment: That's the default value if the caller doesn't provide the argument.

Comment: Why are you asking us what we mean? We didn't tell you anything. Did you mean "What does it mean?"

Comment: @Barmar thank you. Yes, I don't worked so anytime, so I don't know if I can do this.
And yes, If you can explain me, how that work, can u explain?

Comment: If you write `myPHP(["foo", "bar"])` it's the same as writing `myPHP(["foo", "bar"], true)`